# Moving text in tableview cell iphone

Tags: iphone

I have table view cells with cell image and text label and detailed label. 
Problem is cell image is too near to edge of cell(to the left). I want to put some space between edge and cell image. i.e. wants to move image bit away from corner. I have moved that with creating subview and putting image in that. But problem is it now overcome cell text and detailed text as well. I want to move cell text and detailed label to the right as well.

How can i  do that?

For moving cell image, i am using below code:

```
UIImageView *imageview=[UIImageView alloc]]init];
imageView.frame=CGRectMake(10,0,40,40);
[[cell.contentView]addsubview:imageView];
```

But i want to move text and detailed text label as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that image view to move the image.

Subclass `UITableViewCell` and add the following method to the subclass:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect imageFrame = self.imageView.frame;
    imageFrame.origin.x += 10;
    self.imageView.frame = imageFrame;

    CGRect textFrame = self.textLabel.frame;
    textFrame.origin.x += 10;
    self.textLabel.frame = textFrame;

    CGRect detailTextFrame = self.detailTextLabel.frame;
    detailTextFrame.origin.x += 10;
    self.detailTextLabel.frame = detailTextFrame;
}
```

Change `10` to whatever you see fit.

Comment: can u explain how can i subclass uitableViewCell

Comment: `@interface YourTableViewCell : UITableViewCell`

Comment: what is x here? it says no member named 'x' in struct cgrect?

Comment: Ops, sorry... it should be `frame.origin.x`

Comment: Are you using the custom table view cell you just created in your table view controller?